# iPhone: How do I lookup currency conversions?

Tags: iphone, currency

I'm wanting to perform currency conversions in my iPhone app.

Putting aside the issues of number formatting or currency symbols, how do I convert from X USD to Y CAD (or similar)?

I know Google and Yahoo! have APIs which deal with this kind of thing, I just lack the knowledge to access it from my app.

Any code or URLs to examples would be cool.

Thanks,
Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://betterexplained.com/articles/using-json-to-exchange-data/

does that help? scroll to the currency conversion stuff there where there's a datasource mentioned which returns XML. You may then use the NSXML parser to parse the results

check this one as well, looks dead simple:

http://www.exchangerate-api.com/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the links, I was able to get the result I need with the following line:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.exchangerate-api.com/USD/GBP/100?k=<<API KEY>>"]
                                      encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingGB_18030_2000)
                                         error:NULL];
```